# How do you send a request to an express server from a react native app?

Tags: javascript, express, react-native, express-generator

I have 2 separate apps, a `react-native` app and an `express` backend server. I created the server using `express-generator`. My server has the following code in `users.js`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json([{
    id: 1,
    username: "foo"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    username: "bar"
  }]);
});
```

The server is set to listen on port 8080 and have `app.use('/users', users)`. 
Basically, just all of the code that comes with `express-generator`.

In my react native app, I have:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`

And then in `App.js`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/users'
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(users => this.setState({ users }))
}
```

I am using Expo to load my app on an Android device, and am getting:
`unexpected url: /users`. 
If I visit `localhost:8080` in my browser, the data is visible, so I think that the issue must be on the client side.

Comment: Is you're device connected to your wifi?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the complete hostname and port number when making a request. You need to write complete url when getting data as 
*http://localhost:8080/users* in your App.js.

Comment: Thats not true when using proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing the app directly on your mobile device, then in your terminal run "ipconfig" copy the last IP address and paste it into the URL sending a fetch request from your react native app: eg: fetch("http://183.463.57.98:api/endpoint), replace the api and endpoint with your yours.